# Freeware similar to MS Access for SQL-less data mining, querying and reporting

Tags: data-visualization, data-mining, software, sql, database

I am looking for freeware similar to MS Access for data mining, querying and reporting without really writing SQL (which I know very well but sometimes I feel lazy and would rather just drag and drop).  I had used MS Access with ODBC connections to all sorts of external RDBMSs that create an Access pseudo-table as a link that you can do everything with that you can with a regular Access table.

Any suggestions?  I use a `OSX` at work and `Fedora Linux` at home.  I also use `DBeaver` as my multi database SQL client but that does not do GUI query building and reports.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a freeware database program.

Answer (score 2):

[Open Ofice](https://www.openoffice.org/) serves as a freeware alternative to Microsoft Office.  It has a database program called [Base](http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html) that is analogous to Access.

Comment: I don't have it on my Mac, while I do have other parts of Open Office...